# Laravel 5.2 site on localhost/Wamp

Tags: laravel-5, virtualhost

I am trying to learn Laravel.

I created a project on c:/sites where I develop all my sites. I called it larabasic.dev

I cannot open the site in my browser, it keeps switching to www.larabasic.dev and tells me server not found.

I set up a virtual host like I did to all my other sites that works well.

I tried:
1. Changing server.php to index.php and copied the public/htaccess file to the root folder
2. Going to http://larabasic.dev/public
3. Going to http://larabasic.dev/public/index.php
4. Changing vhosts file to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName larabasic.dev
    ServerAlias larabasic.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/sites/larabasic.dev/public"
    <directory "c:/sites/larabasic.dev/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Instead of:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName larabasic.dev
    ServerAlias larabasic.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/sites/larabasic.dev"
    <directory "c:/sites/larabasic.dev">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file has these 2 entries:
127.0.0.1 larabasic.dev And 
::1 larabasic.dev

Nothing helps. Again, any other sites I have developed with plain php work fine.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: When I try it on Chrome, I get this error: ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and I've fixed this by giving `127.0.0.2` to my laravel application.

First, in the hosts file, you need to redirect `larabasic.dev` to `127.0.0.2`:

```
127.0.0.2    larabasic.dev
```

Second, you need to bind the virtual host to that IP:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/sites/larabasic.dev/public"
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName larabasic.dev
    ServerAlias www.larabasic.dev

    <Directory "C:/sites/larabasic.dev/public">
       AllowOverride All
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

       Require local
       # if you want access from other pc's on your local network
       #Require ip 192.168.1
       # Only if you want the world to see your site
       #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my working configuration on my local machine.

Comment: Thanks Taha but that didn't help either.

Comment: I deleted everything from this folder and created an index.php file that echos 'hi'. Still same problem. I copied this index file to another folder called test.dev, that works fine

Comment: I tried creating a project on wamp\www instead, that works, but now, I have to put localhost in my url which I don't want to do. 

Please, can someone help with this?

Comment: are you still trying with a laravel installation?